# How can I change the View of a SharePoint Online folder programmatically?

Tags: sharepoint-online, defaultview

I have a powershell script that creates Folders in SharePoint online.
I'm using Add-PnPFolder to do so.
By default the new folder view is sorted by Name.
I wish to change the default view so that it is sorted by the field Created.
Manually this can easily be done. But programmatically I have no clue how to change the view of a PnPFolder.
Here's the part of the code where I create the folder...

```
Connect-PnPOnline -ClientId $SPO_AppId -ClientSecret $SPO_AppSecret -Url $siteUrl
$connection = Get-PnPConnection
if ($connection) 
{
    Add-PnPFolder -Folder /Team/Acquisition -Name Approvals -Connection $connection
}
```

Get-PnPView only works on PnPLists, not on PnPFolders unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the items displayed in view is configured in the view property, not in item property.
[image]

Code example to change the sorting property of a view:

```
 $Context = Get-PnPContext
 $view=Get-PnPView -List "Documents" -Identity "2B0E08F9-39AC-4553-9343-FDDF3551F77A"
 $Context.Load($View)
 $Context.ExecuteQuery()
 $Query= "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Created' /></OrderBy>"
 $View.ViewQuery = $ViewQuery
 $View.ViewQuery = $QUERY
 $View.Update()
 $Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: Hi Amos
Thanks for your response. 
The thing is, I'm trying to change the view of a single PnPFolder. So there is no -List I can refer to in the Get-PnPView command.

Comment: The view displayed in the folder is the list view, you cannot set a separate view for the folder.